# Error Admob interstitial ads The constructor InterstitialAd(MenuActivity) is undefined

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have written the code for adding interstitial ads from admob to my app's menu activity as per https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced. I have added PERMISSIONS and configchanges in Manifest too. I am getting error in the lines mentioned below:

`

```
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this); // Error: The constructor InterstitialAd(MenuActivity) is undefined

    interstitial.setAdUnitId("lajdID"); // Error: The method setAdUnitId(String) is undefined for the type InterstitialAd

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); //AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

`

Comment: As usual, when you have errors, we would ask that you post the stacktrace so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should import admob from;

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
```

Comment: I was actually using the import: import com.google.ads.Ad;
Your import gives me this error:
The import com.google.android cannot be resolved

Comment: You should add google play service as library to your Project

Comment: You mean GoogleAdmobAdsSdk jar?

Comment: Ok where can I download or how do I import Google Play Service?

Comment: You can find useful Information in https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that MenuActivity is not an instance of android.app.Activity.

Comment: MenuActivity is the activity where I am using that code which I mentioned above.

Comment: Show the code for MenuActivity, because the compiler is telling you that MenuActvity is not an Activity.